# Time Compexity (big-O)Analysis with Probability

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 questions.

1)What is the time complexity (in terms of big -O notation) of code:

```
i = 2
while i <= n:
 if i % 2 != 0:
 i = i - 1
 else:
 i = i * i 
 i = i + 1
 print(i)
```

2)Suppose you have an array of n elements, where each element can be either even or odd
with a probability distribution of 20% even and 80% odd. Propose an algorithm that identifies
the first even element in the array. Describe the algorithm and analyze its average-case time
complexity.

My approach in the first question should have a time complexity of O(logn) since it grows exponentially when the number "i" is less than "n" and even, and it has a constant complexity of O(1) when "i" is odd.

My approach in second question;

> Algorithm:
>
> Start at the beginning of the array. Iterate through the array
> elements one by one. For each element, check if it is even. If you
> find an even element, return its index. If no even element is found
> after iterating through the entire array, return -1 to indicate that
> there are no even elements.

So On average, I need to check approximately 5 elements (1/0.20) before finding an even element.
If an even element is found within the first few checks, the algorithm terminates early.
In the worst case, I may need to iterate through the entire array of n elements.
Therefore, the average-case time complexity can be expressed as O(5) = O(1), which means that, on average, this algorithm requires constant time to find the first even element in the array.

Are my approaches are true?

Comment: please indent your code correctly.